# Remove index.php?var= from URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url with a parameter in it. For instance:

```
domain.com/guidelines/index.php?doc=html
```

I want to convert this to:

```
domain.com/guidelines/html
```

I know it is possible with .htaccess but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the param in php with `$_GET['doc']`, and have the user see the clean url `/guidelines/html` you can rewrite as follows:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/guidelines/(.*)$ /guidelines/index.php?doc=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to put this stuff in

`Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?doc=$1 [NC]`